# Hide or disable app management programmatically

Tags: android, settings

I am working on app for Point of Sale. I need to disable or hide or ignore user to delete any app.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, AdminReceiver.class);
dpm.setUninstallBlocked(cn, packageName, isEnabled);
```

or

```
dpm.addUserRestriction(cn, UserManager.DISALLOW_UNINSTALL_APPS);
```

It needs admin permission (or device owner)